# AutoIncrement _id in pouchdb

Tags: ionic-framework, pouchdb, nosql

I have implemented a queue in pouchDB, where each record is stored as a separate document. Each record resembles a post request, so that when the user is offline I can save the requests in the queue and later on push it to server as soon as user is online. All the requests must be processed in he same sequence as they are generated. But the problem is there is no sequence of _id in the pouch db. So each time a random id is generated and the sequence is lost. What can I do to get the records in the same sequence as they are saved in the database. I am using pouchDB along with IonicFramework.
Thanks.

Comment: Why not using a timestamp as the `_id`?

Comment: I tried it. It works just fine. Thanks

Comment: @fiatjaf You should mention the same in answers (For community purposes)

Comment: I don't think so. It is not a "canonical" answer. It doesn't suit everyone's use cases, that's why I asked. The short and absolutely true answer is: it is impossible to have autoincrement `_id` in PouchDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @fiatjaf:
it is impossible (or not optimal) to have auto-increment `_id` in PouchDB

But, you may opt using a timestamp as the `_id`.

Example, in your doc object:

`doc = { _id : Date.now(), name: 'Pouch DB', description: 'The best DB' }`

Comment: what about the example?

Comment: @AndresChica updated with example

Answer (score 2):

**Pouchdb post**

it Generate automatically

```
db.post(doc, [options], [callback])
```

Create a new document and let PouchDB auto-generate an _id for it.

https://pouchdb.com/api.html

Answer (score 0):

Auto increment is kind impossible. However this is what I did.

Lets say that you are posting something from a form. 
You receive it like this

```
const fromform = req.body.fieldname;
```

Then before adding this and incrementing the _id you can call the alldocs method.

```
database.allDocs({include_docs: true,descending: true,limit:1}).then(function(result){
// the rest of the code goes here
});
```

Then you can use the result to iterate and add a digit to it

```
result.rows.map(function(item) {
            var pusher=JSON.stringify(item.id, null, 4);
            var idf=parseInt(pusher.slice(1,-1),10)
            var addidf=idf+1;
            var sid=addidf.toString();
            doc = {
                _id : sid,
                name: 'field_from_form',
                tagline : fromform // this is also field from form
                }
                    database.put(doc, function(err, response) {
                        if (err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                        } else {
                        console.log("Document created Successfully");
                        res.send("Collection Updated" + JSON.stringify(doc));
                        }
                        console.log("The new array in add tag is pushed is : "+addidf);   
                        });
             });
        }, function(error) {
            res.status(400).send(error);
```

Result row will get you all the docs, however we have sorted it in a descending order and limited it to one. You have an object so we have strigified it. By default pouch will return a string so we parseint it and also slice the quotes. Then we have to add +1 to increment it. Then pouch will not accept number so again you have to convert it to string (phew``)/ You are done.

Yes it is not a good approach but with the lighting speed of pouch. I guess we can overlook it.

Another way is there.
 you can also call the

```
db.info().then(info=> console.log(info.doc_count))
```

The above method is much faster and will save you a lot of overheads, however you will need to somewhat oriented with [object Object] and [object Promise]. I am sure promise will raise eyebrows.

ALL THE BEST !!